# Can't make an infinite carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

All I got was to calculate the width of one element and find what percentage it occupies on the screen, but the transition is not smooth.
codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-fire-ejxvd?file=/index.html

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const arrayOfElements = [];
let currentPercent = 0;
let percentOfElement = 0;

function createSlideElement() {
  const element = document.createElement("span");
  element.className = "slider-element";
  element.innerText = "|my ugly slide|";
  element.style.right = `${currentPercent}%`;
  container.append(element);
  arrayOfElements.push(element);
  const elementWidth = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  percentOfElement = (elementWidth / window.innerWidth) * 100;
}

function step() {
  currentPercent += 0.1;
  for (let el of arrayOfElements) {
    el.style.right = `${currentPercent}%`;
  }
  if (currentPercent >= percentOfElement) {
    currentPercent = 0;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

createSlideElement();
createSlideElement();
createSlideElement();

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `window.innerWidth`, use `container.getBoundingClientRect().width` to calculate the `percentOfElement` like so :-

```
import "./styles.css";

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const arrayOfElements = [];
let currentPercent = 0;
let percentOfElement = 0;

function createSlideElement() {
  const element = document.createElement("span");
  element.className = "slider-element";
  element.innerText = "|my ugly slide|";
  element.style.right = `${currentPercent}%`;

  container.append(element);
  arrayOfElements.push(element);

  const elementWidth = element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const parentWidth = container.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  percentOfElement = (elementWidth / parentWidth) * 100;
}

function step() {
  currentPercent += 1;

  for (let el of arrayOfElements) {
    el.style.right = `${currentPercent}%`;
  }

  if (currentPercent >= percentOfElement) {
    currentPercent = 0;
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

createSlideElement();
createSlideElement();
createSlideElement();
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Working code sandbox :-

[image: Edit Infinite text slider]